# How to understand shopping cart exit rate in goal visualization

Tags: google-analytics

We have a goal funnel set up with these success percentages

(simplified)

1. Shopping Cart (60% success)
2. Checkout (99% success)
3. Checkout Completed (99% success)

Does this mean that 60% of customers entered the Cart and never came back and finished the process. Or could it mean that some of those 60% went to the cart, went back to another product, added another product and THEN continued with the checkout?

I understand backfilling, but if a user enters a goal step, then leaves and returns, is that counted as both a success and a failure, or just a success?

Example:

> You can imagine a scenario like this, if we only have one user who adds a product to their cart and goes back to the home page (1 entrance, and 1 exit on step 1 of the goal funnel, meaning 0% success / 100% failure rate) then adds another product to their cart (2 entrances to step 1 of the goal funnel), and this time then proceeds to checkout.
>
> Will that be reported as 100% success (1 entrance, 1 success - google ignoring the previous failure) or 50% success (2 entrances, 1 success) in the Goal Funnel Visualization

Answer (score 1):

It means that 60% of people had a shopping cart (suggests a small site, some browsers) of those who had a shopping cart, 99% clicked checkout, of those 99% paid, so 0.6*0.99*0.99 = 0.58806 (mental maths, am I right?)

58.806% of people who look at your site end up paying you.

More formally it involves bayers law as the events are not independent, what you actually have is the probability of someone having a shopping cart GIVEN THAT they visit, then what is the probability the checkout GIVEN they have a shopping cart, and then what is the probability they pay GIVEN THAT they proceeded to payment. Hence 58.806% you can just multiply, because you have probabilities in "given that" form already, which is much more useful.

The example in your question will be 100% success rate, will explain why in next edit.

Okay in your example the person adds something to the shopping cart, then leaves, if they then clear their cookies and have no user account with you, when they come back they wont have their shopping cart, the system wont recognise them they'll be the second visitor.

Your 60% is the `P(Have a non-empty shopping cart | they visit your site)` the `|` means given that and `P` is probability.

Let `C` be the event they get a shopping cart, and `V` the event they visit your website:

`P(C|V) = 0.6` thus `P(C'|V) = 0.4` (Probability of not C - no cart - given someone visits)

A visitor is someone who can be tracked as the same person, via cookies or an account name or what have you, it just means "what Google knows to be a visitor"

Next let `M` be the event someone moves onto checkout:

`P(M|C)=0.99` The probability they move onto the checkout given they have a cart is 0.99,

Let `P` be the event they pay you,

`P(P|M) = 0.99`

Thus `P(P|V) = 0.58806`

This means for every 100 people that visit, on average so far (modeling the future is a different thing) 59 of them end up paying you so far.

Of every 100 unique cookies/user-accounts you have 59 of them end up paying you at some point.

Does this help?

Comment: I suppose I am worried that the 60% success rate is artificially low if Google is reporting someone who goes to the cart, and leaves only to return again (perhaps with another product) as an "exit", and later as a success.

Comment: It is reporting "of those with a cart", so 40% of people never click add to cart, it doesn't mean "how many clicked view cart" @Robert also put @ AlecTeal (without the space) please so I get your comments as a notification :) Thanks

Comment: perhaps I'm misunderstanding.. the 60% 'success' rate is 60% of people who add to cart CONTINUE to the next step, the 40% who 'failed' added to cart but never made it to step 2. My question is, are any of those 40% users who went to the cart, bailed (a failure) then came back and continued through checkout (a success) or would google consider the success only and ignore the previous failure.

Comment: No it means "of all visitors" so those who added to the cart but came back at some point (even if it is much later - but are recognised as the same user) count as your 60%, remember the analytics are designed to be useful, they are not simple page counters, this is google, so of everyone who visits your site, 60% of them get a cart, click add to cart and interact with a cart, 99% OF THOSE go onto continue to checkout, and 99% of those end up paying you, so 1% bail before entering card details usually or something.

Comment: I added an example, which I think helps clarify the question. In my goal setup, I have Cart as the first step of checkout, not the rest of the website (Although maybe I should change that) so the goal funnel should only be dealing with those users who make it to the cart, and the 60% 'success' rate on step 1 is read as "60% of people who visit the cart, proceed to step 2 of checkout, 40% do not"

Comment: Sure @Robert give me a sec to get dressed and I'll extend my answer as needed - 5 mins

Comment: @Robert that wasn't 5 minutes but answering now

Comment: @Robert is there anything else? I hate to seem shallow but I want that bounty! :)

Comment: I understand the probability math well enough, I just don't know if Google is reporting a user's second visit to the cart as a single success ("overwriting" the previous failure) or as a success followed by a failure (giving the step's success rate 50% rather than the 100% it's expected to have)

Comment: @Robert it is reporting it exactly as I described.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36402/discussion-between-robert-and-alec-teal)